Is there a way to log start and finish times for installing dotnet sdk on each server
I have an Azure Pipeline PowerShell 5.1 step that installs the .Net SDK on an array of servers. Is there a way to mark start and finish times of the installs for each server?
Install sdk on each server
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -Credential $credential {
        c:\temp\dotnet-sdk-8.0.303-win-x64.exe /install /quiet /norestart | Out-Null
    }


See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.4

You can add $Start = [DateTime]::now just prior to install and $Finish = [DateTime]::now immediately after the install.  While this gets you two variables with the values you want, I'm not clear how you want to log the info.  Save to a file?  What format? Text saying "Installation of $X started at $Start and finished at $Finish"?

Hi Rod, I'm curious which solution you ended up using to achieve your needs? If possible, can you please share your final solution?



Inside the script block executed on each server, record the start time, then, on completion of the installer, output a [pscustomobject] instance that stores the start and completion time, expressed as [datetimeoffset] instances in UTC.

PowerShell's remoting infrastructure automatically adds properties to each output object, notably PSComputerName, which identifies the source computer.

Select-Object can be used to only select the properties of interest.

You can save the output objects to a file, as needed, e.g. by piping to  Export-Csv; you may also want to translate the UTC time stamps to caller-local ones first.


Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers  {
  $start = [datetimeoffset]::UtcNow
  c:\temp\dotnet-sdk-8.0.303-win-x64.exe /install /quiet /norestart | Out-Null
  [pscustomobject] @{
    StartTimeUtc = $start
    EndTimeUtc = [datetimeoffset]::UtcNow
  }
} | 
  Select-Object *Utc, PSComputerName


Another example, just subtracting 2 dates:
icm localhost { $start = get-date; sleep 1; $end = get-date;
  [pscustomobject]@{result = $end - $start } }

result           PSComputerName RunspaceId
------           -------------- ----------
00:00:01.0087160 localhost      2987f4f8-4511-4694-a664-9c418fc5ec97


You can try the following script to get the startTime and the endTime of each installation
# Define the array of servers
$computers = @("Server1", "Server2", "Server3")

# Install SDK on each server and log times
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $startTime = Get-Date
    Write-Host "Starting installation on $computer at $startTime"

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $credential {
        c:\temp\dotnet-sdk-8.0.303-win-x64.exe /install /quiet /norestart | Out-Null
    }

    $endTime = Get-Date
    Write-Host "Finished installation on $computer at $endTime"
}


Thanks for updating, but you do not want to forgo the benefits of parallel execution that passing an array of computers to -ComputerName brings.
Switching to sequential execution, targeting each computer one by one, will dramatically and needlessly increase overall execution time.

Hi @mklement0, yes, agree with you. Thanks for sharing this information!
